# Reszing a border according to text

Tags: html, css

I have a segment of Jquery that pulls comments from youtube and posts them on a page, however, as it stands, the borders around comments are a standard size. I'd like some way of getting this to scale to the amount of text in the comment area if possible.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8JLH7/2/)

Current CSS:

```
.videoComments {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.author {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Please describe in more details how it should look if there is more text in the comment area. Do you want to modify the border width? Do you want to change the sizes of the containers?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do it like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/8JLH7/9/

adding

```
.videoComments {
  float:left;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Oh man, is that what he wants? Makes so much more sense than a bigger border-width, but that's how I interpreted the question.. lol

Comment: @StephanMuller Looks like everyone interpreted it differently!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to update fiddles but here's the code you need:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(retriveComments);

function retriveComments() {
$.get("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/jofNR_WkoCE/comments", function (d) {
    $(d).find("entry").each(function (_, entry) {
        var author = $(entry).find("author name").text(),
            comment = $(entry).find("content").text();
        html = '<div class="videoComments"><div class="inner">';

        html += '<p class="author">' + author + '</p>';
        html += '<p class="comment">' + comment + '</p>';
        html += '</div></div>';

        $('#comments').append(html);
    });
});
```

}

CSS

```
.videoComments {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.author {
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
color: grey;
}
.inner{ border: 1px solid red; display: inline-block; }
```

I've added an extra 'inner' div within the videoComments div an applied the border to that.

Edit: maybe I do know how to update a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8JLH7/7/

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic version that you may want to modify to fit your needs:

After the first two `var` declarations:

```
var border = comment.length / 10;
```

Then update the first line of the html output:

```
html = '<div class="videoComments" style="border-width: '+border+'px">';
```

This will give each comment a border-width of 1px extra for each 10 characters in the comment.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8JLH7/4/

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want the element `.videoComments` to have variable heights?

Use:

```
.videoComments {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-height: 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8JLH7/8/